# Postgresql User Defined Type in primary key constraint

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgresql 9.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. I have a user defined type as one column of a table.  When I create a primary key constraint I get a syntax error.
Here is a sample sql script I'm using with psql to create the table:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS
(
  field1 integer,
  field2 integer
);

CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  my_data my_type,
  other_data integer
);
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT pk_my_table PRIMARY KEY (my_data.field1);
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
>   LINE 1: ...ble ADD CONSTRAINT pk_my_table PRIMARY KEY (my_data.field1);

I've tried using (my_data).field1 but also get a syntax error.

If I just use my_data in the constraint there is no error:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT pk_my_table PRIMARY KEY (my_data);
```

But I would like to use just one field as part of the constraint.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question using google and I'm pretty sure is dead but I still want to answer it cause someone else might see it.

Short answer is *you have to use the field's name*:

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."carga" ADD CONSTRAINT "pk_my_table" PRIMARY KEY ("field1");
```